# CSS borders and strange element boundaries in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ember.js

### Background info:

I'm using ember.js. In my markup I have

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="add">
  {{#view App.AddView id="drop"}}
      {{msg}}
  {{/view}}
</script>
```

and the view for this is like

```
App.AddView = Ember.View.extend({
  dragEnter: function(event) {
    $("#drop").addClass('enter');
    $('#drop').text('Drop it like it\'s hot.');
  },
  dragLeave: function(event) {
    $("#drop").removeClass('enter');
    $('#drop').text('Drag image files here.');
  }
});
```

and the relevant CSS:

```
#drop {
  border: 10px solid gray;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin:auto;
}
#drop.enter {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4pt 4pt lightskyblue;
}
```

### The question:

It seems to be confused about where the edge of the drop region really is. When I drag an image into the window, the shadow and "Drop it like it's hot" message are applied... but only when I'm dragging over the margin around the box, not within the box itself. If I remove the restriction on width and the margins, then it behaves normally. But when there is a margin, it has this strange behavior no matter what I do.

[image: Box model showing margin area.]
[image: Drop message appears when dragging in the margin area.]
[image: Drop message does not appear when dragging over region.]

Am I doing something wrong? This is my first ember.js project. Is there a different way I should be applying the ID to the element created by the view? Is there some targeting thing I should be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue. Seems working fine for me - [demo on emberjs.jsbin.com](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zulehuze/1#/add). You can do some things more Ember.js's way. Controller:

```
App.AddView = Ember.View.extend({
  classNameBindings: [ 'enter:enter:leave'],
  enter: false,
  dragEnter: function(event) {
    this.set('enter', true);
    this.set('text', 'Drop it like it\'s hot.');
  },
  dragLeave: function(event) {
    this.set('enter', false);
    this.set('text', 'Drag image files here.');
  },
  text: ''
});
```

Handlebars template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="add">
  {{#view App.AddView id="drop"}}
      {{view.text}}
  {{/view}}
</script>
```

You can access full code [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zulehuze/1/edit), but rest is just Ember.js starter kit.

Comment: That fixed it. I'm still trying to figure out exactly how.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I used starter kit, you probably have more Ember application code that may cause an issue.

Comment: Not really. I'm using the started kit too and my app doesn't do much of anything yet. I imagine it's something to do with trying to find $("#drop") to apply classes to, versus it already knowing what "this" is? I don't really understand much about Ember yet.